# Screen Processing

Tags: screen, processing

I want to be able to access my computers screen data, which am assuming is 3 2D arrays one Red one for Green and one for Blue. I do not plan on to modifying it just to look for patterns in the 2D matrix. Screen capture will not work. I just want to copy the 2D matrixes that are on screen at any moment in time. Is there any way that I can do this. Any java or c or c++ or anything that can help me read the current screen data. Hope this makes sense.
Lets say I want to create a screen capture software were would I start when it comes to capturing the screen color matrix

Comment: What operating system? If windows, study this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183402(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thank you ya its windows

Answer (score 0):

First off, this isn't really a question for StackOverflow. You should do some research, try something out, and ask a specific technical question. It's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions other than by pointing you to google.

Secondly, your assumption is not valid. This is because you didn't do any research. See point number one.

Thirdly, you've tagged this with [processing], even though it has nothing to do with the Processing language.

But to answer your question, in Java you would do this with the Robot class.